# AWS lambda container /bin/sh Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, containers

I have got this error from AWS lambda container `Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason`
When I run this container locally, I have got `exit code 0`

But when I run this in Lambda I have got the error mentioned above and `exit code 0`.

In both cases, backup creates correctly on `S3`

My container runs this command:

```
FROM alpine:3.14.2

ARG BUILD_ID
ARG BUILD_DATE
ARG VERSION=0.0.9

LABEL maintainer="Rostyslav Malenko"
LABEL version="$VERSION"
LABEL description="This is custom Alpine Docker Image for the create SQL dump from RDS to S3 directly."
LABEL org.label-schema.build-date=$BUILD_DATE

ENV BUILD_ID=${BUILD_ID} \
    APPLICATION_VERSION=${VERSION} \
    SERVICE_ROLE=backup \
    NUMPROCS_WORKER=1 \
    INSTALL_PACKAGES="gzip mysql-client aws-cli" \
    WORKSD="/tmp"

RUN apk -v --update add --no-cache ${INSTALL_PACKAGES} && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* 

WORKDIR ${WORKSD}}

CMD /usr/bin/mysqldump --host=${DB_HOST} --user=${DB_USER} --password=${DB_PASSWORD} --port=3306 \
    --single-transaction \
    --routines \
    --triggers \
    --events \
    --add-drop-database \
    --opt \
    --add-locks \
    --compress \
    --databases ${DB_NAME} | gzip -9 | aws s3 cp - s3://${S3BUCKETNAME}/$(date +"%m-%d-%Y-%H-%M-%S")_${DB_NAME}.sql.gz ; echo $?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[AWS Lambda expects container images to implement a specific interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html#images-reqs), so that the Lambda environment can pass the Lambda invocation event parameters into the container, and so that Lambda can properly parse the response.

You appear to be attempting to run a regular Docker image that does not implement the required AWS Lambda interface. Your use case actually looks like a better fit for AWS ECS + Fargate. If you want to use Lambda you will need to modify your container or rebuild it using one of the provided AWS Lambda base container images.

Comment: Thank you @mark-b
I have rebuilt docker using public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2
But I still have got the same error. Is it possible that AWS Lambda able to run only a code but not a binary file inside container without giving an error?

ECR - for my task will be overcomplicated infrastructure. I need to run few cron tasks once at a week. It looks that old way will better solution. I mean to run a small instance with cron tasks :)

Comment: I didn't mention ECR, I said ECS + Fargate, which would not involve creating any servers, it is serverless, and in my opinion easier to get a docker image like yours running quickly there than on Lambda. As for running a binary on Lambda there is no problem doing that at all, your problem is you still aren't implementing the actual Lambda event handler interface inside your container. In Lambda your container shouldn't exit on its own, it should take an event and process it, and then sit idle until the AWS Lambda service destroys it.

Comment: Thank you @mark-b 
You are right. I will configure ECS + Fargate. It looks the best options. Because launch MySQLDump trough python in a container may not good idea.